# No overload for method matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Tags: c#

I know there are other answers to these types of questions but they usually say that the parameters don't match up but I believe my parameters match up so I don't know why I'm getting the above-mentioned error on my `taskpagenextbtn_Click`. I though that my parameters matched up with the `taskpagenextbtn.Click` line in the `TaskPage` function.

```
public Task_Page(TextBox[] subjectnamearray, List<string> datatablesubjectnamearray, int numofsubjects)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    numoftasks.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender2, e2) => numoftasks_SelectedIndexChanged(sender2, e2,subjectnamearray, datatablesubjectnamearray, numofsubjects);
    taskpagenextbtn.Click += (sender3, e3) => taskpagenextbtn_Click(sender3, e3, numofsubjects);
}
private void taskpagenextbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e,int numofsubjects)
{
    Marks_and_Weighting_Table marksandweightingtable = new Marks_and_Weighting_Table(subjectnamearray, datatablesubjectnamearray, numofsubjects);

    TextBox[] subject1tasksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname1task1weighting, subjectname1task2weighting, subjectname1task3weighting, subjectname1task4weighting, subjectname1task5weighting, subjectname1task6weighting };
    TextBox[] subject2tasksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname2task1weighting, subjectname2task2weighting, subjectname2task3weighting, subjectname2task4weighting, subjectname2task5weighting, subjectname2task6weighting };
    TextBox[] subject3tasksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname3task1weighting, subjectname3task2weighting, subjectname3task3weighting, subjectname3task4weighting, subjectname3task5weighting, subjectname3task6weighting };
    TextBox[] subject4tasksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname4task1weighting, subjectname4task2weighting, subjectname4task3weighting,subjectname4task4weighting, subjectname4task5weighting, subjectname4task6weighting };
    TextBox[] subject5tasksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname5task1weighting, subjectname5task2weighting, subjectname5task3weighting, subjectname5task4weighting, subjectname5task5weighting, subjectname5task6weighting };
    TextBox[] subject6tasksarray = new TextBox[] { subjectname6task1weighting, subjectname6task2weighting, subjectname6task3weighting, subjectname6task4weighting, subjectname6task5weighting, subjectname6task6weighting };

    int i = 0;
    int numberoftasks = Int32.Parse(numoftasks.Text);

    string myString = numofsubjects.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show(myString);
    if (numofsubjects==2)
    {
        while (i<numberoftasks)
        {
            if (subject1tasksarray[i].Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all textboxes.", "Error Message");
                /*https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/496674/EmptyplusTextboxplusValidationplusinplusC*/

                return;
            }
            if (subject2tasksarray[i].Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all textboxes.", "Error Message");
                /*https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/496674/EmptyplusTextboxplusValidationplusinplusC*/

                return;
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: Unrelated: while that code project suggestion works, it's kind of old. You *could* replace it with `if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subject1taskarray[i].Text)`. In my opinion, It's a bit cleaner/clearer.

Answer (score 0):

basically the event handler doesn't allow you to pass the parameters. if you want to pass the parameters then you have to create a delegate instead of directly adding the event handler.

```
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30458/Delegates-in-VB-NET
```

Comment: I'm still not sure how I'm supposed to do his with C#